# ANDROID - Get selected id ratingbar in listview

Tags: android

I've tried to find out how to get selected id of the `ratingBar` in `ListView` on net, but almost of them using `ListViewAdapter` or `RatingAdapter` on another class. I don't know how to do, because I do not yet know about it, so all my classes declared in `MainActivity` including `ListView`.

I have a `TextView` and `RatingBar` on each list in `ListView`,

but the issue is how to send each list of `RatingBar` that already fills into server without create a new class of `ListViewAdapter` or `RatingAdapter`??

here is my full code how it's work to display the `TextView` and `RatingBar` on each list:

```js
public class Pertanyaan extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = Pertanyaan.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    private Button kirim;
    private RatingBar rate;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pertanyaan);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        TextView textdosen=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dosen);
        TextView textmatkul=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.matkul);
        final TextView txtrate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtrating);
        kirim = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        rate=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String dosen=b.getString("dosen");
        String matkul=b.getString("matkul");
        textdosen.setText(dosen);
        textmatkul.setText(matkul);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Pertanyaan.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Menampilkan Pertanyaan...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "http://flix.16mb.com/send_data.php";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");

                        HashMap<String, String> pertanyaans = new HashMap<>();

                        pertanyaans.put("id", id);
                        pertanyaans.put("ask", ask);

                        contactList.add(pertanyaans);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Pertanyaan.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_pertanyaan, new String[]{"ask", "id"}, new int[]{R.id.ask, R.id.txtid});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

can someone give me a hint what should i do?

Comment: anyone have an idea please?!!!

Comment: first of all where is the setOnItemClickListener for your listview?

Comment: Thats should i ask, i dunno where to put the setOnClickListener or onClickListener to my code, i've been tried to add that in any code, but i cant read the error from logcat, i need some idea

Comment: no for listview you need onItemClickListener....and also you need a custom adapter. SimpleAdapter is simple(limitations to string only) you have to build a custom adapter. Also another advice is to use recyclerview

Comment: I know that i need that, but i don't know how to use it, however i've the reference, and takes several weeks to implement any code from internet to my code, i stuck at this point,

Comment: Sorry for useless question,

Comment: check my answer. You can then get the id or the ask wherever you want to place them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a sample application so that it should give you some help:

First of all you need to create a `CustomAdapter` because `SimpleAdapter` has limitations. Secondly you need to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. After that you need to register a click event when the user clicks on the list that you have made. For those things we come with the following:

The Model of the list:

```
public class CustomList {
    private String id, ask;

    public CustomList(String id, String ask) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ask = ask;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAsk() {
        return ask;
    }

    public void setAsk(String ask) {
        this.ask = ask;
    }
}
```

then the layout for each list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id_text"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ask_text"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

then the layout for `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="kostas.testexample.com.testexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then the custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder>{
    private List<CustomList> items;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(List<CustomList> items, Context context){
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemId.setText(items.get(position).getId());
        holder.itemAsk.setText(items.get(position).getAsk());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView itemId;
        TextView itemAsk;

        CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemId = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_text);
            itemAsk = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ask_text);
        }
    }

}
```

then you add them all up in `MainActivity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private URL url;
    private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String id, ask;
    private List<CustomList> customList = new ArrayList<>();
    private StringBuilder jsonResult;
    private JSONObject jsonChildNode;
    private JSONArray jsonResponse;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        accessWebService();
        clickEvent();
    }

    private void clickEvent() {
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(MainActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item Clicked at position: " + position + " with id: " + customList.get(position).getId() + " and ask is: " + customList.get(position).getAsk(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }));
    }


    public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, List<CustomList>> {
        public JsonReadTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
           // pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<CustomList> doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(in, MainActivity.this);
                jsonResponse = new JSONArray(jsonResult.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                    jsonChildNode = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
                    ask = jsonChildNode.optString("ask");
                    customList.add(new CustomList(id, ask));
                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return customList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<CustomList> customList) {
            if(customList == null){
                Log.d("ERORR", "No result to show.");
                return;
            }
            ListDrawer(customList);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }

    public static StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is, Activity activity) {
        String rLine;
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            activity.finish();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private void ListDrawer(List<CustomList> customList) {
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(customList, MainActivity.this);
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute("http://flix.16mb.com/send_data.php");
    }
}
```

and then you need the customListener for `RecyclerView`

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private OnLongItemClickListener mLongListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    interface OnLongItemClickListener{
        boolean onLongItemClicked(int position);
    }

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnLongItemClickListener listener) {
        mLongListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

but do not forget to add to build.gradle(Module: app) the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```

and in your Manifest.xml the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Hope it helps and give you a hint on how to do stuff!!!

Comment: but sir, as you say, i need a ratingbar.onClickListener, so
should i create a new adapter for rating or i can add ratingClick into one of the code?

Comment: you can use customList.get(position).getId() in your clickListener for the ratingbar