# Update ListView with AsyncTask and adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I am trying to build ListView from AsyncTask.
The problem is that i have an ImageView in all items of my listView.
In my class apadter(ChallengeAdapter) i need to check if this button ImageView is clicked once or not and switch that i will change the ImageView(imageView.setImageResource(...)).

> This is my class adapter(ChallengeAdapter)

```
   package com.example.daly.bigchallenge;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import java.util.ArrayList;


   public class ChallengeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Challenge> {
   Challenge currentChallenge;
   ImageView imageViewParticipateChallenge, imageViewLikeChallenge;


public ChallengeAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Challenge> challenges) {

    super(context, 0, challenges);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.challenges_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    currentChallenge = getItem(position);


    TextView textViewTitleChallenge = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleChallenge);
    textViewTitleChallenge.setText(currentChallenge.getChall_title());

    TextView textViewDescriptionChallenge = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescriptionChallenge);
    textViewDescriptionChallenge.setText(currentChallenge.getChall_description());

    imageViewParticipateChallenge = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewParticipateChallenge);
    imageViewLikeChallenge = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLikeChallenge);

    if (currentChallenge.chall_is_liked_by_current_user == 1)
        imageViewLikeChallenge.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
    else  if (currentChallenge.chall_is_liked_by_current_user == 0)
        imageViewLikeChallenge.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);

    imageViewParticipateChallenge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("clicked", "clicked");
        }
    });
    TextView textViewNbrLikesChallenges = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNbrChallengeLikes);
    textViewNbrLikesChallenges.setText(Long.toString(currentChallenge.getChall_nbr_likes()));

    imageViewLikeChallenge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("clicked", "clicked");
        }
    });


    return listItemView;
}
```

}

The AsyncTask is into my activity (HomeActivity).
In my AsyncTask i send a request (URL such as script PHP) to get Data from dataBase in the server.
The response is a JSONObject and it works.
I think that the problem is getView( of class ChallengeAdapter) is called more then one time so that why the building of listView is wrong.
Some help please

Comment: no ViewHolder implementation? I recommend to switch to recyclerView instead. It has much advantages and it´s easy to switch: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html  &   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: There is no solution with ListViiew ?

Comment: of course there is, you need to implement a ViewHolder pattern. But that´s because I told you to switch. Before doing all this changes to make a listview work correct, you can easily do it by switching to recyclerView. RecyclerView has a default implementation of the ViewHolder pattern. Somedays the ListView will be out of date and not used anymore and maybe deprecated. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: i will try it. thanx!

Comment: see my answer here on how to upgrade from listview to recyclerview...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957568/android-get-selected-id-ratingbar-in-listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957568/android-get-selected-id-ratingbar-in-listview)

Comment: Thanx it works with RecycleView